# arrange multiple column in descending order and assign date value

Tags: r

I want to sort (data1, data2 and data3) in descending order and after that I want to assign respective date instead of values in (data1, data2 and data3) column.

```
 date    data1  data2 data3
 1970/1  5        8    7
 1971/1  7        4    2
 1972/1  3        3    4
 1973/1  2        0    54
 1974/1  0        50   12
 1975/1  8        8    6
 1976/1  10       2    4
 1977/1  20       3    1
```

I would like to get output like this

```
data1   data2   data3
1977/1  1974/1  1973/1
1976/1  1970/1  1974/1
1975/1  1975/1  1970/1
1971/1  1971/1  1975/1
1970/1  1972/1  1972/1
1972/1  1977/1  1976/1
1973/1  1976/1  1971/1
1974/1  1973/1  1977/1
```

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Which one do you want sorted? You can't pick all three. Only one can be sorted.

Comment: I want to sort data1 and assign date value after sorting... and i want to do same operation for other columns too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh slightly late...

```
apply(df[,2:4], 2, function(d) df$date[order(d, decreasing = TRUE)])
```

Comment: `lapply()` is generally more appropriate for data frames, especially when working over columns.  Here you could also do `as.data.frame(lapply(df[-1], function(x) df$date[order(-x)]))`.  Basically the same as what you have, just with `lapply()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is round-about way to do it..@stephen solution is the way to go.

```
df <- data.frame(date,data1,data2,data3)
rownames(df) <- df$date 

df1 <- df[order(df$data1, decreasing = TRUE), ]
df$data1 <- rownames(df1)

df2 <- df[order(df$data2, decreasing = TRUE), ]
df$data2 <- rownames(df2)

df3 <- df[order(df$data3, decreasing = TRUE), ]
df$data3 <- rownames(df3)
new.df <- subset(df, select = data1:data3)
rownames(new.df) <- NULL
new.df

   data1  data2  data3
1 1977/1 1974/1 1973/1
2 1976/1 1970/1 1974/1
3 1975/1 1975/1 1970/1
4 1971/1 1971/1 1975/1
5 1970/1 1972/1 1972/1
6 1972/1 1977/1 1976/1
7 1973/1 1976/1 1971/1
8 1974/1 1973/1 1977/1
```